Server not able to find some of JS files in JSP application
I have JSP web application hosted on wildfly sever, it was working even after recent deployment.
Today application seems broken and server not able to find some JS files.

This is my file structure, but when I click on store.min.js from error message I see a default html file.
Do any one have idea about this.


For starters, that looks like HTML. I don't know why there would be html in a javascript file to begin with.

Looks like the appropriate .js files are missing from the resulting web deployment archive (war)? Did you check they are there?

Be aware that Windows is case insensitive to file names, whereas normally file names are case sensitive. In your case however it seems that the minified (compacted) versions are not deployed. Normally during development the full non-minified versions are used as they are readable by the developer. So some deployment configuration.

@Rado, Yes I verified. The files are there in server war bundle.

If your app is not started then you can't get it directly from your browser. If it's started, then  you should map *.js files to a default servlet, which is capable  to return them as a resource. If you cannot access these files from the browser, then you can open them in the file manager or from the project source folder.
